# Change CSS height when you click outside of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a mobile menu:
Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qo81bunh/

In the code, when u click on the button to expand the menu, this is the code:

```
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}
```

when u click on the "X", here is the code to collapse it:

```
.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}
```

i think each time u click on the button, it changes the max-height.

My question is how do u make it so when u click somewhere else other than the button/"X", it will close the menu if it's open. thanks

how can i do this in css if possible? if not, jquery?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to this with javascript (or jquery) by adding an event listener when clicking the document. It can then check if the menu is active (in your case the input is checked), and then close it.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var btn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
  if (btn && btn.checked) {
    btn.click();
  }
});
```

I have edited ur jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qo81bunh/1/

Comment: is there any thing that works for all browser? it doesn't work on firefox